# Transcoding and Streaming a video file for Android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, video-streaming, mp4, video-encoding

I'm trying to encode a local/static input file (can MP4, for example) into a smaller video file (either by resizing, lesser quality video, etc.) and stream it **in parallel** (i.e. I can't wait for the encoding process to finish before streaming it back), so it can be played by an **Android** client (the standard Android video player).

So I've tried using ffmpeg as follows:

```
ffmpeg -re -i input.mp4 -g 52 -acodec libvo_aacenc -ab 64k -vcodec libx264 -vb 448k -f mp4 -movflags frag_keyframe+empty_moov -
```

*Notice I'm using stdout as the output so I can run ffmpeg and stream its output on the fly*

However, such methods (and other similar methods) don't seem to work on Android - it can't simply play it once it receives "non-standard" files (such as a fragmented MP4s) - it seems like the empty moov atom messes it up.

I also tried other container formats, such as 3GPP and WebM.

I'd love to hear any kind of input on this issue...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can specify multiple outputs in ffmpeg, see here http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Creating%20multiple%20outputs

For Android if newer than 3.0 try HLS as an output

Comment: Why would I need multiple outputs? By the way, the only type of HLS Android supports is MPEG-TS, but that makes the entire video unseekable...